# My loop through folder code in Excel macro is giving an error of file not found

Tags: excel, vba

I'm collating or appending data one below other using the below code to copy paste data in a sheet from different Excels with same format stored in a folder

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook

MyDir = "Z:\MIS & ANALYTICS\RPA\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir)
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
  Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rws, 27))
    Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheets1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
  End With
  MyFile = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Here `MyFile = Dir(MyDir)` is searching file name as **`"xyz.xls"`** whereas in folder its only **`"xyz"`** hence its giving me an error stating file not found

Comment: My guess is the MyDir path having  " & " might be the problem. Could your try from your local storage with a path like "C:\temp\" (ebnsuring temp folder already exist)

Answer (score 2):

The `Dir` function returns only the filename, not the path, so you have to append that again when you use it:

Change this line

```
Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
```

to this

```
Workbooks.Open MyDir & MyFile
```

And remove this:

```
ChDir MyDir
```

AND you are using `x1Up` instead of `xlUp` (That `1` should be an L: `l`) see the difference? That mistake is in multiple locations in your code, so make sure to fix all of them.

Comment: This was quiet helpful now the code works perfectly fine, thanks alot braX

Comment: Glad you were able to get it to work. Please accept this answer so that it does not remain as an open question. There is a little checkmark near the top of my answer to click.